# Правильно ли реализованы IEnumerator's для чтения CSV?

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода, csv

Я реализовал простенький `IEnumerable<CSVLine>` для чтения `CSV` файлов.

Правильно ли реализованы `IEnumerator<>`ы?

**CSVStream:**

```
public class CSVStream : IEnumerable<CSVLine>
{
    private readonly char[] _separators;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<char> Separators
    {
        get { return _separators; }
    }

    public CSVStream(string filePath, Encoding encoding = null, params char[] separators)
    {
        Encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        _separators = separators ?? new []{','};
        FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public Encoding Encoding { get; }

    public string FilePath { get; }

    public IEnumerator<CSVLine> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CSVStreamEnumerator(FilePath, _separators, Encoding);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

**CSVStreamEnumerator:**

```
public class CSVStreamEnumerator : IEnumerator<CSVLine>
{
    private readonly StreamReader _fileStream;
    private CSVLine _current;
    private readonly char[] _separators;

    public CSVStreamEnumerator(string filePath, char[] separators, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        Encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        _separators = separators;
        _fileStream =
            new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding);
    }

    public Encoding Encoding { get; }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; protected set; }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        string currentString = _fileStream.ReadLine();
        return !((currentString is null
            ? _current = null
            : _current = new CSVLine(currentString, _separators)) is null);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _fileStream.DiscardBufferedData();
        _fileStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        _current = null;
    }

    public CSVLine Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fileStream == null || _current == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            return _current;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _current = null;
        _fileStream?.Close();
        _fileStream?.Dispose();

        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    ~CSVStreamEnumerator()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

**CSVLine:**

```
public class CSVLine : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly string[] _values;

    public CSVLine(string value, char[] separators)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }

        _values = value.Split
        (
            separators ?? new[] {','},
            StringSplitOptions.None
        ).Select(s => s.Replace("\"\"", "\x0000").Trim('\"').Replace("\x0000", "\"")).ToArray();
    }

    public CSVLine(string[] values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _values.Length; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CSVLineEnumerator(_values);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public static implicit operator CSVLine(string val)
    {
        return new CSVLine(value: val, new []{','});
    }

    public static implicit operator CSVLine(string[] values)
    {
        return new CSVLine(values);
    }
}
```

**CSVLineEnumerator**

```
public class CSVLineEnumerator : IEnumerator<string>
{
    private int _currentIndex;
    private string[] _values;

    public CSVLineEnumerator(string[] values)
    {
        _values = values;
        _currentIndex = -1;
    }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; protected set; }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_currentIndex == _values.Length - 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _currentIndex++;
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _currentIndex = 0;
    }

    public string Current
    {
        get { return _values[_currentIndex]; }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            _values = null;
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    ~CSVLineEnumerator()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Чтение через `foreach`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EnumeratorTest()
{
    CSVStream stream = new CSVStream("D:\\test.csv", Encoding.UTF8, ';');

    foreach (CSVLine csvLine in stream)
    {
        foreach (string value in csvLine)
        {
            Console.Out.Write("\'{0}\' ", value);
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

За основу взял тестовый текст из википедии:

```
1965;Пиксель;E240 – формальдегид (опасный консервант)!;"красный, зелёный, битый";"3000,00"
1965;Мышка;"А правильней использовать ""Ёлочки""";;"4900,00"
"Н/д";Кнопка;Сочетания клавиш;"MUST USE! Ctrl, Alt, Shift";"4799,00"
```

На выходе получил такйо результат:

```
'1965' 'Пиксель' 'E240 – формальдегид (опасный консервант)!' 'красный, зелёный, битый' '3000,00' 

'1965' 'Мышка' 'А правильней использовать "Ёлочки"' '' '4900,00' 

'Н/д' 'Кнопка' 'Сочетания клавиш' 'MUST USE! Ctrl, Alt, Shift' '4799,00'
```

P.S. Знаю что вот этот кусок кода:

```
_values = value.Split
(
    separators ?? new[] {','},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
).Select(s => s.Replace("\"\"", "\x0000").Trim('\"').Replace("\x0000", "\"")).ToArray();
```

Выглядит как *"бред сивой кобылы"*, но другого способа безболезненого удаления двойных кавычек и удаления ковычек из теста я не нашел =).

Comment: у вас класс называется `CSVStreamEnumerator`, а читаете вы не поток, а конкретный файл. Я бы принимал поток как параметр и читал из потока, класс получится более гибкий. Сможете и потоки из памяти егму подставлять или читать с буфером.

Comment: ну и как бы - `CSVStream : IEnumerable<CSVLine>` - так это поток или это коллекция/перечисление?

Comment: Думаю потоковое перечисление =)

Comment: ну тогда вам надо обратиться к S из SOLID )

Comment: В .NET есть готовый класс, правда, по историческим причинам, он находится в пространстве имён Basic, но его можно вызывать из C#. `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`. Если же вы хотите самостоятельно разработать реализацию, то 1) используйте `yield` вместо реализации `IEnumerator` и 2) делайте полноценный лексический разбор строки, потому что значения в кавычках могут содержать кавычки и запятые.

Comment: А еще значения могут содержать перевод строки, да и кавычки не обзятельны. В общем если ограничиться упрощенным форматом, то можно и так, но полная спецификация csv несколько сложнее.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko этот готовый класс имеет свои недостатки. Например, он не умеет работать с большими файлами. Возможно, автор вопроса задался задачей обойти данное лимитирование.

Comment: @ヒミコ как написал rdon бывают ячейки которые могут в себе иметь символ перевода строки. Такие ячейки так же обрамляются в кавычки. Подпишусь на вопрос, мне интересен конечный код, который выйдет у тебя ^_^

Comment: @Andrew, не сумел нагуглить ничего про ограничения. Не ошибаетесь? Интерфейс у класса такой, что он читает файл построчно. Никаких сверх-ресурсов для этого ненужно даже на больших файлах. Разве что каждая строка занимает по мегабайту, но это странно для CSV.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko я пользовался даной либой и уткнулся в ограничение. Уже не помню точно про то какого размера должен быть файл, но оно точно есть. Мне приходилось разделять данные на несколько файлов что бы это обойти. Попробуй сделать эксперимент с записью рандомных строк в большом количестве и проверь сам когда программа отвалится с ошибкой.